# Изменение цвета элемента кода VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio

Хочу изменить цвет комментариев на серый в Visual Studio. Каким образом это сделать?

Comment: в vs code так https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/change-color-of-comments-in-vscode, может поможет

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88BsSjG5iQQ&themeRefresh=1

Comment: Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Comment > Item foreground

Answer (score 1):

Украду с комментария @Alexander Petrov -а

`Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Comment > Item foreground`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Заходим в 'settings.json'
2. Вставляем туда этот объект:

```html
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": { 
    "comments": "#0aef47" 
},
```

3. Вместо #0aef47 ставим код нужного цвета
4. Сохраняем и радуемся

Comment: Это VS Code? А почему в вопросе Visual Studio?

Comment: Уставший был, ошибся :D